# Uniform integrability and convergence in probability

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence, uniform-integrability

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two families of random variables, such that $X$ is uniformly-integrable and $Y \rightarrow c$ in probability to $c \in \mathbb{R}$. I have to show that for all $\epsilon >0, $ $$ P(|X_n(Y_n -c)| > \epsilon) \rightarrow 0~\text{in probability.}$$

I would really appreciate any hints or tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $M>0$. $|X_n(Y_n-c)|> \epsilon$ implies $|X_n| >M$ or $|Y_n-c| >\frac {\epsilon} M$. Uniform integbrability implies that given $\eta >0$ we can find $M$ such that $P(|X_n| >M)<\eta$ for all $n$. Hence $P(|X_n(Y_n-c)|> \epsilon) <\eta+ P(|Y_n-c| >\frac {\epsilon} M$. The second term tends to $0$ so the proof is complete.

Comment: If your definition of uniform integrability says $\sup_n \int_{\{|x_N>M\}}|X_n|dP \to 0$ use Chebyshev's in equality $P(|X_n| >M) \leq \frac 1 M \int_{\{|x_N>M\}}|X_n|dP$.

Comment: We have $|X_n(Y_n -c)| > \epsilon$ then $|X_n| > \frac{\epsilon}{|Y_n - c|}$ or $|Y_n - c| > \frac{\epsilon}{|X_n|}$ so there exists $M$ such that $|X_n| > M$ or  $|Y_n - c| > \frac{\epsilon}{M}$ ? Am I right ?

Comment: Prove by contradiction: if $|X_n| \leq M$ and $|Y_n-c| \leq \frac {\epsilon } M$ then $|X_n(Y_n-c)|$ would be $\leq \epsilon$.

Comment: Last question: $P(|X_n(Y_n -c)| > \epsilon) = P(|X_n| > M \vee |Y_n - c| > \frac{\epsilon}{M}) \leqslant P(|X_n| > M) + P(|Y_n - c| > \frac{\epsilon}{M})$?

Comment: $P(A \cup B) \leq P(A)+P(B)$ always.